# Which Admin table has databse names in it in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I understand that we can do "show databases" in snowflake to get the details of databases. But is there any admin table which i can query.
Actually in my result set I need only database names. 
There is an option to use RESULT_SCAN but i am trying to avoid the same.
please advise.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`INFORMATION_SCHEMA`](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/info-schema.html) ,  and in particular[`INFORMATION_SCHEMA.DATABASES`](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/info-schema/databases.html)`, e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.DATABASES
```